Get connections error when using the Azure Database online Migration Service
I have an onpromise schema, around 111 GB, and I want to migrate it to Azure MySQL using their online Migration Service. It works great for any other schema and table. Still, in this particular schema, there is one huge table, and it always ends up with an error: Unable to get a valid MySQL connection for server 'xx.xxx.xx.43' because all '8' connections in the pool are broken.
Any idea about this? How do I debug the issue in source DB and Azure DB?
Thanks!

My source's db has the max_connections limit of 2048, so I'm not sure where the "8" connection comes from.

You should contac MS Azure support tean for help as thus question is about using their tool for migrating a database. This is not a programming question.

I have contacted Azure support, and they said it is my local DB issue.
Besides, why can I not ask a question that is not a programming question?
Any reference? I tagged this question with MySQL, database, and Azure, so it is supposed to be not a programming question.

Reference that you asked for: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Fixed.
There is an advanced migration setting in DMS, and I can update the connection size; otherwise, it will be determined by the run time, which is 8.
